# Regular Expression to identify all camel cased strings in a document

Tags: javascript, regex

I am rusty on regular expressions and need some help. A js code base inherited is using a mix of camel case and snake casing for things like variables names and object properties.

I am trying to formulate a regular expression I can use that will identify all the camel cased strings, and then be able to replace those strings with snake casing. The part I am struggling with is identifying the camel cased strings under the conditions I have.

Identifying which strings are camel case: In this document, all camel cased strings start off with either a lower case letter, an underscore, or a $, and then will Use a capital Letter at some point later in the string. Examples are: `someCamelCasedString` & `_someCamelCasedString` & `$someCamelCasedString`. The regular expression would need to take into account that some of these strings I am trying to match for may be object properties, so it should be able to identify things like: `Foo._someCamelCasedString.bar` or `Foo[_someCamelCasedString].bar`

Comment: FYI I've fleshed out the answer to consider some refinements and edge cases. Let us know if it needs to go in a different direction.

Comment: Thanks @zx81, your answer was perfect! Sorry for the delay on the upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This identifies all occurrences of "strict" camel case (only letters). Whether they start with `_` or `$` or `foofoo` doesn't matter.

```
[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*
```

An edge case is `cameL` Is that proper camel case? I have assumed it is, but we can change that.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ4qQ6)

If you want to allow other characters in the string (digits etc) then we can add them in the character classes. So this is a starting point to be refined depending on your requirements.

For instance if you know that you're happy with digits and underscores, you can go with this:

```
[a-z]\w*?[A-Z]\w*
```

If you also want to allow dollars in the name (a character that @Jongware says js strings allow) you can go with this:

```
[a-z][\w$]*[A-Z][\w$]*
```

Then there is the question of what constitutes the **boundary** of a valid string, so that we can perhaps devise some anchor (perhaps with sneaky lookaheads, since js doesn't support lookbehinds) in order to avoid false positives.

Comment: Note: JS does not allow dashes in names, but it does allow underscore, digits, and a couple of unexpected characters (`$` comes to mind -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names for a full list. I hope the OP is not finding variables in "καμήλαΥπόθεση" :))

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for your input, changed the "dashes" example to a "dollars" example. :)

Comment: @PaulT Hey Paul is this solved, or are you still having trouble with it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
/(\w|\$)+([A-Z])\w+/gm
```

You can play around with it here and see the examples: http://regexr.com/38qkq The site also explains what each piece means in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:^|\s|[^\w$])([a-z_$][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)/gm
```

Test http://regex101.com/r/pH1aB7